# Why do the prayers stop in Tagore's "A Dream"?

Tags: poetry, bengali-language, rabindranath-tagore

At the end of Rabindranath Tagore's "[A Dream](https://allpoetry.com/A-Dream-------English-Translation)", there's one part (the ending) that goes like this:

> At the gate
> The lamp went out
> In the temple
> On the banks of Shipra
> The prayers stopped.

This comes after the rest of the poem is describing coming home to "my beloved", with descriptions of this woman and their emotions. But what relevance does this last part have? Why is it important that "the prayers stopped"? Why finish the poem with this?

Comment: well, quite literally, the lovers meet up as a prayer service is going on in the temple. The service ends. ‍♂️

Answer (score 4):

The narrator dreams of a visit to the ancient city of Ujjayani, on the banks of the Kshipra river. Ujjayani was the capital of the [Avanti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avanti_(Ancient_India)) kingdom that flourished roughly 700 BCE–300 BCE. The [Mahakal Shiva temple](http://dic.mp.nic.in/ujjain/mahakal/default.aspx) referred to in the poem still stands in modern [Ujjain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ujjain), though the current building dates back only to the 18th century.

As with any temple, services are conducted at specific times of the day. The poem's setting is sunset:

> In the temple of Mahakal
> The evening prayer bell rang
> The crowded roads were now empty
> The dusk was falling
> And the rooftops were glowing
> With the rays of setting sun.

A sunset *আরতি / aarati*, worship rite, would be part of the temple's schedule. The bell for beginning that rite has rung just before the narrator arrives at his former lover's house, and the rite ends as he is seated beside her. The end of the prayers is consistent with the poem's timeline.

In the original, the poem ends as follows:

> রজনীর অন্ধকার
> উজ্জয়িনী করি দিল লুপ্ত একাকার।
>           দীপ দ্বারপাশে
> কখন নিবিয়া গেল দুরন্ত বাতাসে।
>           শিপ্রানদীতীরে
> আরতি থামিয়া গেল শিবের মন্দিরে।

> rajaniir andhakaar
> ujjayinii kari dila lupta ekaakaar.
>           diip dvaarapaashe
> kakhana nibiyaa gela duranta baataashe
>           shipraanadiitiire
> aarati thaamiya gela shiver mandire

Literal translation (mine):

> The darkness of the night
> rendered Ujjayani hidden, indistinguishable.
>           The lamp by the door
> was long extinguished by a gust of wind.
>           On the banks of the river Shipra
> The worship rite ended in Shiva's temple.

As always, Tagore's specific descriptions are wonderfully evocative. The blotting out of Ujjayani by the darkness, and the extinguished lamp by the beloved's door, could signify just the end of the dream. It could also be an acknowledgment that this is only a dream. If the narrator is paying homage to a lost love by dreaming of her, then the end of the dream is also the end of the homage, rather like the end of a worship rite.

I'm not sure I agree with the other answer given here, which states that the lovers have reached a state of perfection. One reason to question that interpretation is found in Tagore's own translation of this poem.

"[A Dream](https://allpoetry.com/A-Dream-------English-Translation)" is Kumud Biswas's translation of Tagore's Bengali poem *[স্বপ্ন](https://www.tagoreweb.in/Verses/kolpona-41/swopno-1530) / swapna*, "Dream". The poem was published in the 1900 collection *[কল্পনা](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.11143/page/n3/mode/2up) / kalpanaa*, "Imagination". The date of composition given at the end of the printed poem in that collection is *৯ জ্যৈষ্ঠ ১৩০৪, 9 jyaiShTha 1304*, which [corresponds](http://www.banglatext.com/bangla-date-converter.html) to 23 May 1897 in the Gregorian calendar. Tagore's own rather truncated translation of this poem was published as [Poem 62](https://allpoetry.com/In-The-Dusky-Path-Of-A-Dream) in the 1913 collection *[The Gardener](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/6686/6686-h/6686-h.htm)*.

*The Gardener* 62 ends on a rather despondent note:

> I thought and thought; our names would not come to my mind.
> Tears shone in her eyes. She held up her right hand to me. I took it and stood silent.
>
> Our lamp had flickered in the evening breeze and died.

This undercuts any optimistic reading of the end of the original or the translation. In all versions, the entire poem underlies the lack of connection between the lovers, who don't even speak the same language any more. I believe the connection between the prayer's ending and the darkness that falls around the lovers suggests the acknowledgment of loss rather than the attainment of perfection. It's true, of course, that the darkness and silence gives the lovers the opportunity to be intimate; but even in that case it seems more a last farewell than a new beginning.

**Notes**:

1. The usual disclaimer: my Bengali is dreadful, so rely on the translations above AYOR
2. The Romanized Bengali is transliterated using the [iTrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRANS) scheme.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the end of the poem sees the lovers reunited, with total perfection (reference to the lotus):

> Like a lotus bending on its stem, she slowly bent her head on my breast

So, the prayers stopping is most likely about the end of the need for prayer, as all is now fulfilled.